# How can i select from 2 tables some relationed fields in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Im new in python-django and i really need some help. This is my first question here. I´ve searched a lot on similar questions here but didnt find my needs. I am working on a restaurant website, developing in python and django and im facing very difficulties to make the restaurant menu. This data of the menu stays in a mysql db.

I searched for select_related and prefetch related a lot, i imagine one of these will help, but its not working.

So, i have 2 tables, category_menu and menu. I have to list all categories and all the items of these categories.

I have 2 models, category_menu and menu:

```
class category_menu(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    class Meta:
    default_related_name = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name_category

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('category_menu_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class menu(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category_menu,related_name='categories', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    default_related_name = 'menus'

def __str__(self):
    return self.item

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('menu_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Im my views, i have the following:

```
query = category_menu.objects.prefetch_related('categories').all().distinct
datamenu = {'object_list': query}


return render(request, template_name, datamenu)
```

In my html, just the categories are listing, but the relationed items of the menu are not.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used "categories" in both `category.Meta.default_related_name` and in `menu.category.related_name`. That could be causing some problems.

Try removing `related_name='categories'` from `menu.category` so that it looks like this:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(category_menu, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Fix the indentation of your `menu` model. `Meta`, `__str__()` and `get_absolute_url()` should all be indented the same as they are on the `category_menu` model, e.g.:

```
class menu(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category_menu, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # These have been indented
    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'menus'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('menu_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Migrate the database, then attempt getting your queryset without prefetch:

```
query = category_menu.objects.all()
```

In your template, you can use nested `for` tags to list the categories and menu items within each category. Something like this:

```html
{% for category in object_list %}
<h2>{{ category }} ({{ category.menus.count }})</h2>
{% for item in category.menus.all %}
<div>
    <h3>{{ item }}</h3>
    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
    <div>${{ item.price }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If it works, try prefetching using the `default_related_name` on your `menu` model:

```
query = category_menu.objects.prefetch_related('menus').all()
```

Comment: For sure my template is not ok. Should i do some nested for, to list all menus from the category_menu?

Comment: Hi Tato - yes, you will need nested `for` tags. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Made it, but dont returns any menu item. I think im very close to a happy ending, but stills returning nothing

Comment: OK. I've updated the answer with information about indentation in your `menu` model. Try that and see how you go. You shouldn't need to migrate after making that change.

Comment: Im sorry for the bad identation here, but was just here. On my code is already idented.

Comment: In this case, do i need the <form></form> tags in my template? Without them, the categories are listing.

Comment: You shouldn't need `<form>` tags for this purpose. Can you check in the database to ensure that menu items exist, and confirm that they are linked to your categories.

Comment: Off course. I have an admin interface in this site, and all is running well. I can make some crud and the tables are working properly. My main problem is to list in the right way.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added an item count to the template code. Let me know if any count displays a value other than `0`.

Comment: Great, in the categories that have some menu items in the db is showing the number of item menus.

Comment: Mr. MattRowburn. You did it. i was forgeting a little detail in my template. The nested for was the problem. I have no words to thank you. It took 45 days to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not focusing on the answer here, but it may be a step to solution at least.

on menu model, could you please change the field:

`category = models.ForeignKey(category_menu, related_name='categories', null=True,`

to this one:

`category = models.ForeignKey(category_menu, related_name='menus', null=True)`

Comment: menus is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: because you need to change this too. (from categories to menus): query = category_menu.objects.prefetch_related('categories').all().distinct   AND no need for all(), distinct() is OK.